# "Bookending" values from a source Observable

Tags: rxjs

I'd like to "bookend" values flowing down a stream. More concretely, from a source like this

```js
import { of } from "rxjs";
let start$ = of(1,2,3);
```

I'd like an Observable that emits

```
// 1-enter
// 1
// 1-exit
// 2-enter
// 2
// 2-exit
// 3-enter
// 3
```

I can do this by adding a Subject in the middle, for example:

```js
import { of, Subject } from "rxjs";
import { startWith, pairwise, delay } from "rxjs/operators";

let start$ = of(1, 2, 3).pipe(delay(1000));

function createBookendedStream(start$) {
  let input$ = start$.pipe(startWith(undefined), pairwise());
  let output$ = new Subject();

  input$.subscribe(function ([prev, curr]) {
    if (prev) output$.next(prev + "-exit");
    output$.next(curr + "-enter");
    output$.next(curr);
  });

  return output$;
}

createBookendedStream(start$).subscribe(console.log);
```

This works exactly like I'd expect, but it feels kind of hacky. I feel like I'm missing something. Is there a more canonical approach, e.g., using operators?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is a nice way of mapping each element to a multiple, and then flattening the results into a single observable (sounds like a case for `flatMap`*!):

```js
const bookended$ = start$.pipe(
  flatMap(el => from([$'{el}-enter', el, $'{el}-exit']))
);
```

But `flatMap` doesn't guarantee each subsequence will be fully flattened in order, without following 'enters' getting merged in before the preceding 'exits' (I think in your case it would work because there are no arbitrary delays or timings involved, but I'm not 100% sure)

`concatMap` guarantees you nicely ordered behaviour, though at the cost (probably insignificant) of increased memory usage as it has to maintain a buffer:

```js
const bookended$ = start$.pipe(
  concatMap(el => from([$'{el}-enter', el, $'{el}-exit']))
);
```

* also known as its alias `mergeMap`

Comment: I think you've said it well. I wouldn't think `flatMap` would ever emit out of order, but for the sake of clarifying the intention, I'd go with `concatMap` since it makes it obvious the order is important.